# Open new Terminal Tab with OS X JavaScript for Automation

Tags: applescript, osx-yosemite, javascript-automation

I am playing around with JavaScript for Automation on OS X Yosemite.

I am trying to open up a new tab in the terminal application. Here is what I've got so far:

```
var Terminal = Application('Terminal);
var Tab      = Terminal.Tab;

// Activate the Terminal App, creates a new window if there isn't one already
Terminal.activate();

// This contains all the windows
Terminal.windows;
// This contains the first window
Terminal.windows.at(0) // alternatively, Terminal.windows[0]

// This contains the tabs in the first window
Terminal.windows.at(0).tabs
```

The `Terminal.windows.at(0).tabs` is essentially an array. It has a `.push` method. I assumed that I could use the following statement to add a tab to the window:

```
Terminal.windows.at(0).tabs.push(new Tab());
```

but it throws a very general error:

```
Error -10000: AppleEvent handler failed.
```

The documentation is severely lacking and I'm thinking that this JavaScript for automation thing was just a gimik to get JavaScript developers onboard.

Note: I've seen AppleScript solutions that essentially just tell the `System Events` Application to press Command + T to open up a new tab. That feels very hacky and makes Command + T hardcoded in there.

Comment: "Terminal.windows.at(0).tabs is essentially an array" -- This is incorrect. It's actually a query object ("object specifier") describing a one-to-many relationship between a window object and its tab objects. (JXA's implementation is FUBAR, its documentation lies, and Apple support for users virtually non-existent. Welcome.) Though on this occasion the real culprit is Terminal's crappy Apple event interface: its `make` command is totally broken and has been for years. So you'll either have to resort to GUI Scripting, or else get yourself a better terminal emulator app like iTerm. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

the following code works for `chrome` and `safari`, but not work for `terminal`, I am still figuring out the reason, see if this info helps.

```
chrome = Application("Google Chrome")
newTab = chrome.Tab()
chrome.windows[0].tabs.push(newTab)
```

Answer (score 1):

see if the following work in your case:

```
var system = Application('System Events');
var terminal = Application('Terminal');

// tell application "Terminal" to activate
terminal.activate();  

// tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down
system.keystroke('t', {using: 'command down'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate the shortcut for one new tab. Also need declare the target tab

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
```

Look the example with two or more tabs

```
teel application "Terminal"
    do script "cd ~/ && ls" in tab 1 of front window
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
    do script "cd ~/Applications && ls" in tab 2 of front window
end tell
```